# How to set up webcontext name for spring boot application with external tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat7

I am using external Tomcat for Spring-Boot MVC application and I'm unable to set the webcontext name in the application.property file. For internal Tomcat, the property **server.context-path** is working fine. 
Can any one explain how to do it for external Tomcat ?

Comment: When you say internal tomcat do you mean the embedded tomcat and when you say external tomcat do you mean when deploying spring boot as a WAR file?

Answer (score 0):

When you're deploying a Spring Boot application to Tomcat as a war file, your options for setting the context path are the same as they are for any other app.

The simplest way is to use the name of the file that you deploy to control the app's context path. For example, if you copy `foo.war` into Tomcat's webapps directory, its context path will be `/foo`.